# why does ("" + null = "") in C# but ("" + null = "null") in Java?

Tags: c#, java, null, string

The part I don't understand is the point of having the String representation of null be the String "null". What's the rationale behind that functionality in Java?

Is there a deeper answer than "that's just the way it is" in Java?

Comment: I can see that. I just wonder what's the reasoning behind the decision to have the string representation of null be "null" in java. Is there a deeper answer than "that's just the way it is".

Comment: Because an empty string is not null. So if you see an empty string being printed/logged, how would you distinguish a null value from it?

Comment: @BalusC Then, in C#, why is the *inverse* true? This entire question is .. well, closed :D

Comment: @pst: sorry, C# is beyond me. I just do Java.

Comment: @JohnSmith 'Is there a deeper answer than "that's just the way it is".' - the fact there isn't can be deduced from the fact two different platforms have done something different without computers catching fire. Meaning, it's an arbitrary choice.

Comment: @millimoose I think that this could be answered in some reasonable sense .. *but* it'd require having documentation/resources to the people responsible for making this decision and to what the rationale was. I find those questions not a good fit for SO, and quite hard to find an accurate source for - it's not asking for why it is now, but why it was done so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to see that a value is null, you expect to see null.

```
System.out.println(null);
```

prints

```
null
```

And

```
Integer a = null;
System.out.println("a= " + a);
```

prints as you would expect

```
a= null
```

As to why C# doesn't do this, I don't know.  I imagine the designers made different assumptions about what `null` means.  IMHO it shouldn't be the same as an empty string.

Comment: But in C# is is *not* this way and the question is "Why not?" (Which is a poor question.)

Comment: -1 because this is not an answer to the question. "What's the rationale behind that functionality in Java (as compared to C#)?" This was a poor question. It would take a large case - not just showing how it works - to argue an answer.

Comment: @pst the OP doesn't ask why in C#, only why in Java.  Since you don't believe this is the answer, I look forward to your answer. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I believe it's a poor question and voted to close as Not Constructive. However, my -1 was hasty, I suppose ..

Comment: @pst, it doesn't help when the question has been changed at least once. ;)

Comment: Very roughly, the Java rationale is "if you accidentally used a null string you want to be aware of it." The C# rationale is "if you intentionally used a null string you don't want it cluttering things up." There's a case to be made for either option.

Comment: It's not unusual for, say, an empty list to be represented by `null`. A bad practice, but when did that stop people. Seems reasonable that if you were into bad practice, you'd want a null string reference to be interpreted as an empty string. Indeed some bad practice Java libraries do just that.

Comment: If you were using `null` when really you shouldn't I would want this to be obvious in any messages rather than invisible. ;)

Answer (score -2):

Because the String "null" does not equals object null.

When you do this "" + null, the null object get casted to String, then i can compare stirng "null"

Comment: did you read the question?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but merely repeats part of it.

Comment: i Didnt read after you edited the question, this is a poor question and its not good for this comunity, go and ask James Gosling, Mike Sheridan, Patrick Naughton and someone from microsoft and ask them  that.